# Need help re-writing a recursive funtction to non-recursive algorithm

Tags: python, recursion

I found out that I can't use recursion on my micropython platform, because this implementation has no stack protection and continues happily writing the funtion calls into the heap.

Now I have to re-write this recursive python code, and I still have not found a solution!

Here some explainations what the landmarks are:

layer - how "deep" the recursion is, right now. The deepest layer depends on the list self.blobs, if layer is len(self.blobs) - 1, the recursion should return, otherwise recurse again.

firstID and lastID are parameters for finding out whether a combination is possible or not (found out in self.differenceValid())

possibleQueues is the return value.
self.possibleLandmarkIDs is a nested list containing numbers, like:

```
[[0, 2, 4], [6, 8, 1, 3], [0, 2, 4], [1, 3]]
```

len(self.blobs) and len(self.possibleLandmarkIDs) are equal

If you have questions, feel free to ask. I hope you can help me!

```
def findQueueCombinationsRecursive(self, layer, firstID, lastID):
    possibleQueues = []
    for index in range(len(self.possibleLandmarkIDs[layer])):
        landmarkID = self.possibleLandmarkIDs[layer][index]
        if layer == 0:
            firstID = self.possibleLandmarkIDs[layer][index]
            lastID = self.possibleLandmarkIDs[layer][index]
        if self.differenceValid(firstID, lastID, landmarkID):
            if layer == len(self.blobs) - 1:
                possibleQueues.append([])
                possibleQueues[len(possibleQueues)-1].append(landmarkID)
            else:
                deeperList = self.findQueueCombinationsRecursive(layer + 1, firstID, landmarkID)
                if len(deeperList) == 0:
                    continue
                for item in deeperList:
                    possibleQueues.append([])
                    possibleQueues[len(possibleQueues)-1].append(landmarkID)
                    for i in item:
                        possibleQueues[len(possibleQueues)-1].append(i)
    return possibleQueues
```

Comment: There are many sites and examples describing how to convert recursion to iteration (and vice versa).  How did none of these help you to write even a small attempt?  You also fail to specify what this function does, describe the algorithm, show sample input and output, and provide a driver routine.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can almost always convert a recursive algorithm into an iterative one by using a stack. Here's a quick stab at transforming your code (using a list as the stack), though I might have got some small bits wrong:

```
def findQueueCombinationsRecursive(self):
    results = []
    stack = [(0, None, None, [])] # items on the stack are 4-tuples
    while stack:
        layer, first_id, second_id, queue = stack.pop()
        for landmark_id in reversed(self.possibleLandmarkIDs[layer]):
            if layer == 0:
                first_id = second_id = landmark_id
            if self.differenceValid(first_id, second_id, landmark_id):
                new_queue = queue + [landmark_id]
                if layer == len(self.blobs) - 1:
                    results.append(new_queue)
                else:
                    stack.append((layer+1, first_id, landmark_id, new_queue))
    return results
```

If you don't care if the order the results are in is the same as your recursive code, you could get rid of the `reversed` call in the `for` loop. Since the stack is LIFO (last in, first out), we need to push the items in reverse order in order to pop them off the stack in the original order.

You might also consider dramatically different approaches to solving your problem. For instance, I think you could generate all possible queues with `itertools.product(*self.possibleLandMarkIDs)`. You'd then need to filter out the invalid queues by calling `self.differenceValid` method for each step of each candidate queue.